# Does Japan charge an extra departure tax if you depart from a different airport than your arrival?

Tags: japan, nrt, taxes, hnd

I'm a Turkish citizen. I'm planning to visit Korea and Japan in 2018 with tourist visa. My most likely route will be Seoul - Osaka- Tokyo - Istanbul.

I was told by the airline company that if I leave Japan from another airport than the arrival, Japan takes extra tax and so I should turn back to my first arrival point.

Is it true and if this is the case, how much should I pay for leaving from Tokyo?

Comment: How would you travel from Osaka to Tokyo? If you don't fly they probably meant that they (the airline) will charge more for an open jaw ticket. You can't fly directly from Osaka to Istanbul anyway...

Comment: I will take train between Osaka and Tokyo.

Comment: By asking your airline or booking agent providing a breakdown of these fares, taxes, charges and fees, you could help yourself and others understanding the difference.

Comment: Totally untrue. You can book two one-way tickets with different airlines and who will find out where you arrive and depart...

Answer (score 9):

As far as I'm aware, **that's not true**.  There are departure taxes which vary slightly based on the airport you use, but it makes no difference if you arrived at the same one or not.  Simple counterexample: if you book a one-way flight out of Japan, you're not asked where you flew into on your way in.

There are two international airports in Tokyo, namely Narita and Haneda.  At time of writing, Narita Airport charges 2610 yen if departing from Terminal 1 or 2, or 1540 yen if leaving from Terminal 3, which is used by low cost carriers only: https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/faq_ask/psfc

Haneda Airport charges 2570 yen: http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/dept/psfc.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly the person you were talking to was trying to convey, but even if there were higher taxes in that situation, you have to take the whole trip in consideration and compare for yourself.

Taking 3 random dates (July 5, 12 and 17 respectively for each of the 3 legs), I see the following possible return flights (with IST-ICN and ICN-KIX non-stop in all cases):

- KIX-ICN-IST (no direct flight possible): from 1102 euros.
- TYO-ICN-IST: from 867 euros.
- TYO-IST non-stop: from 1261 euros.

Fares may vary with differing dates, flights, classes, etc. of course, but it's obvious that leaving from Tokyo does not necessarily make things more expensive *per se*.